# how can draw cross sectional of electrical machine?

Tags: tikz-shape

how can i draw a cross sectional of electrical machine like this:
[image]

can you help me please?

Comment: Could you be specific in terms of what you're currently struggling with? Perhaps provide the community with something you've tried via a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv)...

Comment: Instead of piling up questions consider to accept answers to your other posts first in order to appreciate the work of users who are willing to help you.

Comment: I didn't vote down, but are you having trouble with the whole picture? Or are there things you know how to do and others you don't know? It's usually nice if you can at least provide the parts you know how to do, so other users can focus on the stuff you don't know or you're stuck with.

Comment: Your question leaves all the effort to our community, even typing the essentials of a TeX document such as `\documentclass{}...\begin{document}` etc. As it is, most of our users will be very reluctant to touch your question, and you are left to the mercy of our procrastination team who are very few in number and very picky about selecting questions. You can improve your question by adding a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that more users can copy/paste onto their systems to work on. If no hero takes the challenge we might have to close your question.

Answer (score 4):

This kind of picture doesn't require particularly elevated skills, but having an intermediate knowledge of the `\foreach` statement will help you draw it with a relatively short code. Basically we can draw the smaller circles with a single foreach.

### Output

[image]

### Code

```
\documentclass[margin=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, shapes.misc}

\tikzset{
    cross/.style={draw, label={[font=\large]center:$\times$}, circle,
        inner sep=1mm, outer sep=0pt},
    dot/.style={draw, circle, inner sep=1mm, outer sep=0, label={[fill=black, circle, inner sep=.5mm]center:}},
    point/.style={fill=black, circle, inner sep=1pt, node contents={}},
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) circle (2cm);
\draw (0,0) circle (2.5cm);
\draw (0,0) circle (3.5cm);

\foreach \one/\two [count=\xi, evaluate=\xi as \angle using int (60*\xi)] in {rb/sB, ra'/sA', rc/sC, rb'/sB', ra/sA, rc'/sC'}{
    \pgfmathsetmacro\switch{int(mod(\xi,2)) ? "cross" : "dot"}
    \node[\switch, label={\angle+195:\one}] at (\angle:1.85cm) {};
    \node[\switch, label={[label distance=-1mm]\angle-25:\two}] at (\angle-30:2.65cm) {};
}

\draw[-{Latex}] (0,0) -- (0,5) node[above] {sQ};
\draw[-{Latex}, dashed] (0,0) -- (120:5cm) node[above left] {sB};

\draw[-{Latex}] (0,0) -- (5,0) node[below] {sD};
\draw[-{Latex}, dashed] (0,0) -- (25:5cm) node[below right] {$r\alpha$};

\draw[-{Latex}] ++(4,0) node[point] arc (0:25:4) node[point] node[midway, right] {$\theta_{r}$};

\draw[-{Latex}] ++(20:6) arc (15:25:6) node[midway, right] {$\omega_{r}$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you Alenanno. Your code is professional, so i don't share my code.

Comment: @MojtabaMansouri You should share your code as well. When other people point out the errors, that's when you learn. :)

Comment: If you think his code is right and professional, think about accepting his answer...

Comment: @Douwe66 his answer is good for professional person that can understand his code.

Answer (score 0):

```
\documentclass[margin=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}             
\def\inwinding#1#2#3#4#5{
\begin{scope}[shift={#1}, rotate=#2]
\draw [fill=white](0,0) circle (2mm) node[yshift=#3,xshift=#4]{#5};
\draw [thick](1.414mm,1.414mm) -- (0,0) -- (-1.414mm,-1.414mm);
\draw [thick](-1.414mm,1.414mm) -- (0,0) -- (1.414mm,-1.414mm);
\end{scope}
}
\def\outwinding#1#2#3#4#5{
\begin{scope}[shift={#1}, rotate=#2]
\draw [fill=white](0,0) circle (2mm) node[yshift=#3,xshift=#4]{#5};
\draw [fill=black](0,0) circle (0.5mm);
\end{scope}
 }
  \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]      
  \coordinate (A) at (0,0);
  \coordinate (B) at (5,0);
  \coordinate (C) at (25:5cm);
  \coordinate (F) at (90:5cm);
   \coordinate (G) at (120:5cm);
    \draw[fill=white] (0:3cm) arc (0:360:3cm);
    \draw[fill=white] (0:2cm) arc (0:360:2cm);
    \draw[fill=gray!30] (0:1.75cm) arc (0:360:1.75cm);
% % % for rotor:       
 \outwinding{(0:1.45cm)}{0}{-5mm}{0mm}{$\mathbf{c^{'}}$}
  \outwinding{(120:1.45cm)}{0}{2mm}{5mm}{$\mathbf{a^{'}}$}
  \outwinding{(240:1.45cm)}{0}{3mm}{-3mm}{$\mathbf{b^{'}}$}

 \inwinding{(60:1.45cm)}{0}{-2mm}{4mm}{$\mathbf{b^{}}$}
  \inwinding{(180:1.45cm)}{0}{4mm}{0mm}{$\mathbf{c^{}}$}
   \inwinding{(300:1.45cm)}{0}{-1mm}{-4mm}{$\mathbf{a^{}}$}
 % % % for stator
 \outwinding{(330:2.3cm)}{0}{5mm}{2mm}{$\mathbf{C^{'}}$}
  \outwinding{(90:2.3cm)}{0}{0}{-4mm}{$\mathbf{A^{'}}$}
    \outwinding{(210:2.3cm)}{0}{-5mm}{3mm}{$\mathbf{B^{'}}$}

 \inwinding{(30:2.3cm)}{0}{4mm}{-2mm}{$\mathbf{B^{}}$}
   \inwinding{(150:2.3cm)}{0}{-5mm}{-2mm}{$\mathbf{C^{}}$}
     \inwinding{(270:2.3cm)}{0}{0}{5mm}{$\mathbf{A^{}}$}
 % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % %555        
\draw[very thick,->,black] (A) -- (B) node [at end,sloped,right,black]{{\small{sD} }} coordinate (sD axis);
   \draw[->,dashed,very thick,black] (A) -> (C) node [at end,sloped,right]{{\small{$r\alpha$} }}; 
      \draw[->,very thick,black] (A) -> (F) node [at end,rotate=-90,sloped,yshift=2mm,black]{{\small{sQ} }}coordinate (sQ axis);
       \draw[->,dashed,very thick,black] (A) -> (G) node [at end,rotate=-290,sloped,yshift=2mm]{{\small{$r\beta$} }};
      \draw[->] (0:4cm) arc (0:25:4.0cm) node [midway,sloped,above]{{\small $\theta_{r}$ }};       
      \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You could post this in the other answer, or better yet, in the question. :)

Comment: @Alenanno, this is own answer on his question. Its look fine.